# Combining S column type with makecell \thead

Tags: siunitx, makecell

I am trying to have nicely aligned numerical values in my table (alongside potential empty cells or text), with `\thead` table headings to have multi-line column descriptions. When I try the following, I encounter two issues with the headings (but the table body is perfect):

1. `*` seems prepended to the column names
2. the column name *centered* overflows the table (which may be caused by 1)

[image: S column heads problem]

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hb]
\sisetup{detect-weight,
         mode=text,
         table-format=4.3,
         table-space-text-post={*}
         }
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lSSSS}
\toprule
  & \thead{multi\\(level)} & \thead{columns} & \thead{here} & \thead{centered} \\ \midrule
A & 12.444 &  & 0.03* & 213.2 \\
B & ns & 0.025* & 0.005** & 12.26 \\
C & 0.23 & ns & 9156.6 & 4563.22 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

There are a lot of "Missing $ inserted" errors so I assume that the column headers are interpreted as math columns even though they aren't. How can I improve this? Preferably in a `renewcommand` or similar approach so that I don't have to manually change every pre-existing too much.

Comment: Enclose the `\thead` commands in a set of `{}`.

Comment: Since you showed a screenshot and mentioned various error messages: Please be aware, that even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error. Therefore, don't even look at the output, but fix all error messages first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclosing all `\thead` commands in a set of `{}` results in a compilable MWE and the following output. I also added a set of `{}` around all other non-numerical entries in the table columns.

From the `siunitx` manual:

> Cell  contents  which  are  not  part  of  a  number  can  be
> protected  using  braces,  as illustrated.  Cells
> which contain no numerical data at all are aligned using the
> setting specified  by  the `table-text-alignment` option,  which
> recognises  the  values `center`, `left` and `right` (Table 39).

Lastly, and since all columns contain different types of numbers, I used individual `table-format` and `table-space-text-post`options for all 4 columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l
                S[table-format=2.3]
                S[table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post={*}]
                S[table-format=4.3, table-space-text-post={**}]
                S[table-format=4.2]
                }
\toprule
  & {\thead{multi\\(level)}} & {\thead{columns}} & {\thead{here}} & {\thead{centered}} \\ \midrule
A & 12.444 &  & 0.03* & 213.2              \\
B & {ns}   & 0.025*   & 0.005** & 12.26    \\
C & 0.23   & {ns}     & 9156.6  & 4563.22  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! This is probably a silly question... but what exactly does encapsulating with `{}` do?

Comment: Adding a set of `{}` around cell contents that are not (part of) a number basically hides them from the parser and aligns the contents based on the `table-text-alignment` option (centered is the default here).